# How to use Turkish characters in .bat file while indicating path?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I just want to create basic code to open multiple files with one click. Problematic part is here

```
D:
Start "" "D:\Dersler\1 (Birleştirilmiş Klip).mp4"
```

My filenames usually contains Turkish special characters such as ç ö ş ğ ü ı Ç Ö Ş Ğ Ü I. So, whenever I open my .bat file, it cannot find the path for the file.

I tried to add chcp 65001 or chcp 857 in the beginning of my code, didn't work.

First time I create this code, I write it on wordpad.exe and saved as Text document MS-DOS. I also changed .txt to .bat. It somehow converted my Turkish characters to ‡ or symbols like that. However, when I tried this again, it did not convert. So, this method didn't work too.

What is the very basic solution for my problem?

Comment: The first thing you need to be aware of is that in order for an `.mp4` file to execute in this manner, the default application, registered to run it, is read from the registry, and the filename is passed to that application as an argument, according to the command defined for it there. You therefore have unknowns, because we don't know what command/argument is actually being passed to the application. What happens when your `Start` command uses filenames with different scenarios of spaces, parentheses, and Turkish characters? e.g. `"1Klip.mp4"`, `"1 Klip.mp4"`, `"1(Klip).mp4"`, `"müzik.mp4"`.

Comment: the code page of the batch file must match the code page you're setting, i.e. UTF-8 for `chcp 65001` and CP857 for `chcp 857`

Comment: @Compo, `Start` command works very well with all of them. It automatically opens the file whit MPC-HC. Problem begins with files Turkish characters.

@phuclv, I tried to add `chcp 65001` or `chcp 857` in the beginning of my code, didn't work.

Comment: Well if you know what program is running the file, what happens when you open your mp4 file directly using it, instead of wasting resources finding out which application to use. Example: `Start "" "P:\athTo\MPC-HC\mpc-hc.exe" "D:\Dersler\1 (Birleştirilmiş Klip).mp4"`

Comment: [Photo](https://imgur.com/6giCnNI)